# modifying angular ngsw-worker.js

Tags: angular, angular14, angular-service-worker, ngsw-config

I need to mdify the ngsw-worker.js file in angular14, but I am wondering is it possible or not!?
and how can I rename the ngsw-worker.js to like ngsw.js?

this file is located in my app node-module

Answer (score 0):

You register the script for your service worker when importing the `ServiceWorkerModule` in your application module:

```
imports: [
  ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
],
```

You could pass any other file name for your service worker there with your custom content.

See for more information [the official Angular documentation on the `ServiceWorkerModule` here](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/ServiceWorkerModule#serviceworkermodule).